# Construction of measure by linear functional

Tags: real-analysis

The exercise 6.9 in the book  by Stein and Shakarchi state that

Let $C([a,b])$ be the vector space of all real valued continuous functions on the interval $[a,b]$. If $\ell$ is a positive linear functional on $C([a,b])$ such that it is positive in the sense that $\ell(f)\geq0$ if $f\geq 0$, then there exists a unique Borel measure $\mu$ on $[a,b]$ such that 
$$
\ell(f) = \int_{a}^b f \mu(dx)
$$

The hint the authors give is to define some function $F:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ as $F(u)$ being the limit of $\ell(f_\epsilon)$ where $f_\epsilon$ is defined as
$$
f_\epsilon(x) = \begin{cases}
1&\text{for }a\leq x\leq u\\
0&\text{for }u+\epsilon\leq x,
\end{cases}
$$
and linear in $[u,u+\epsilon]$, which looks very similar to the charateristic function. Then, $F$ turns out to be right continuous inducing a measure such that 
$$
\mu([a,x]) = F(x)
$$
Then, the authors say like it is pretty clear that
$$
\ell(f) = \int f d\mu
$$
which doesn't seem trivial to me at all.

To establish this, using the definition of $F$, I have proved the identity for all monotone functions $f$, then I have smoothly approximated any continuous function since any smooth functions can be written as the difference of two monotone functions.

I would like to know if there is any simpler proof of the last identity after constructing a measure, or if there is any other simpler way to solve the problem.

I am well aware of the construction of measure when $[a,b]$ is replaced by some compact metric space $X$. But I mean this is just the 9'th problem and I was expecting a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the statement of the Riesz Representation Theorem for positive linear functional. It's Theorem 2.14 of Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis.